# Polymorphic has many though with STI in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've faced unusual situation with rails association and created simple sample to show that. 
Assume we have 4 models:
1) list.rb

```
class List < ApplicationRecord;end
```

2) show.rb

```
class Show < List;end
```

3) joined_table.rb

```
class JoinedTable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :work
end
```

4) work.rb

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :joined_tables, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lists, through: :joined_tables, source: :listable, source_type: 'List'
  has_many :shows, through: :joined_tables, source: :listable, source_type: 'Show'
end
```

Thus we have next schema.rb

```
create_table "joined_tables", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "listable_id"
  t.string   "listable_type"
  t.integer  "work_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end

create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "type"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "works", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Now when you got all the info, could anybody explain me why when I'm trying

```
Work.first.shows
```

it generates

```
 Show Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" INNER JOIN "joined_tables" ON "lists"."id" = "joined_tables"."listable_id" WHERE "lists"."type" IN ('Show') AND "joined_tables"."work_id" = ? AND "joined_tables"."listable_type" = ?  [["work_id", 1], ["listable_type", "Show"]]
```

that looks like a proper request, but when I'm trying to do

```
Work.first.lists
```

it generates

```
  List Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" INNER JOIN "joined_tables" ON "lists"."id" = "joined_tables"."listable_id" WHERE "joined_tables"."work_id" = ? AND "joined_tables"."listable_type" = ?  [["work_id", 1], ["listable_type", "List"]]
```

which IS NOT THE SAME and missing checking lists.type.

I know that is poor architecture and one probably should use scope on associations in Work leaving aside polymorphism in JoinedTable, but that's just something I've faced in project that came up to me. Also I'd love to hear alternative solutions to that, but most of all I'd like to know why rails generates different queries.

P.S. In example I'm using rails 5 and SQLite. But in real project using rails 4 and postgres it's even worse. If I do first Work.first.shows and then Work.first.lists it generates

```
  List Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" INNER JOIN "list_works" ON "lists"."id" = "list_works"."listable_id" WHERE "list_works"."work_id" = $1 AND "list_works"."listable_type" IN ('List', 'Show')  [["work_id", 50]]
```

but if I do Work.first.lists at once it generates

```
  List Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" INNER JOIN "list_works" ON "lists"."id" = "list_works"."listable_id" WHERE "list_works"."work_id" = $1 AND "list_works"."listable_type" = 'List'  [["work_id", 50]]
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Work.first.lists` doesn't generate `lists.type` because `List` is the base class in the hierarchy, so lists are all records of all types in the `lists` table. Also, keep in mind that all `List` records will have `type = nil` in DB, since `List` is the base class.

Furthermore, when you use polymorphic association with STI, it by default always assigns the name of the base class to the `*_type` column of polymorphic association. In your case `listable_type` of `JoinedTable` will always be `"List"`

The second problem is because when you do `Work.first.lists` first, Rails doesn't know that there is the child `Show` class, since it hasn't been loaded yet at that moment. You should whether make it autoload by accessing it (it happened when you did `Work.first.shows`), or use something like `require_dependency`.

Here is a working solution for you:

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :joined_tables, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lists, -> { where(type: nil) }, through: :joined_tables, source: :listable, source_type: "List"
  has_many :shows, -> { where(type: "Show") }, through: :joined_tables, source: :listable, source_type: "List"
end
```

Comment: STI base classes store their class name in the `type` column, same as any child class.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @chumakoff! Makes a lot of sense.
Just'd like to clarify one thing, does it mean, that to use such architecture properly there should be some base class and both List and Show should be inherited from it?

Comment: The other question is how it shoud've been done in proper way? 
I think there should be 
has_many :lists, -> { where('lists.type = \'List\'') }, through: :joined_tables
has_many :shows, -> { where('lists.type = \'Show\'') }, through: :joined_tables, source: :list
in Work
and
belongs_to :list, foreign_key: 'listable_id'
in joined table
which lets us not to use polymorphism in joined table and works properly.
Maybe you have a better approach @chumakoff?

Comment: You don't need a separate base class for List and Show in your case, but I think that if you had it, that would be better and might save a lot of time and nerves in the future.  I edited the answer and added a working solution. Please, read it again from the beginning to the end.